# AWS boto3 CloudWatch Events put_rule - Invalid type for parameter EventPattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to run the following code:

```
response = events.put_rule(
    Name = "DEMO_EVENT",
    EventPattern = ({
        "source": [
            "aws.ec2"
        ],
        "detail-type": [
            "Notification"
        ],
        "detail": {
            "state": [
            "running",
            "shutting-down"
            ],
            "instance-id": [
            "i-***",
            "i-***"
            ]
        }
    }),
    State="ENABLED"
)
```

Keep on getting the following error:
type: , valid types:

I tried changing many things but still not able to run it. Can someone please tell me what the mistake is?

Comment: Please include the exact error message.

Comment: As @jarmod mentioned, we can't say for sure what's wrong. One thing I see is that the detail-type can have certain values only. One such would be: "EC2 Instance State-change Notification". Try changing yours to this and check. Details about event patterns can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEventsandEventPatterns.html

Comment: @jarmod - botocore.errorfactory.InvalidEventPatternException: An error occurred (InvalidEventPatternException) when calling the PutRule operation: Event pattern is not valid. Reason: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{'source': ['aws.ec2'], 'detail': {'state': ['running']}, 'detail-type': ['EC2 Instance State-change Notification']}"; line: 1, column: 3]

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 - Made change still getting above error.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. This might help someone else in the future:

```
response = events.put_rule(
    Name = "DEMO_EVENT",
    EventPattern = """
        {
        "source": [
            "aws.ec2"
        ],
        "detail-type": [
            "Notification"
        ],
        "detail": {
            "state": [
            "running",
            "shutting-down"
            ],
            "instance-id": [
            "i-***",
            "i-***"
            ]
        }
    }
    """,
    State="ENABLED"
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Noviceme, that helped to set this up:

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Noviceme, that helped me to set this up:

```
account_id = boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('Account')

response = event.put_rule(
    Name='Lambda_s3_trigger',
    State='ENABLED',
    Description='trigger lambda when file is uploaded to s3',
    EventPattern="""{"account": ["account_id"]}"""
    )
```

Comment: `json.dumps({"account": ["account_id"]})` would also work